# A Difficult Application of Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Looking to input a $p$ for the first line:

```
p=6;
```

Build a list of primes from the 3rd to $p-1$:

```
plist=Table[Prime[n],{n,3,p-1}];
```

Then build a list as follows:

```
bmod=Outer[Mod,{3*Prime[p]},plist]
```

---

Here's the code so far with the output:

```
p=6;
plist=Table[Prime[n],{n,3,p-1}];
bmod=Outer[Mod,{3*Prime[p]},plist]

{{4,4,6}}
```

---

Now I'd like to multiply each element of the list by $2$, **but** keep them mod their original prime, so instead of:

```
{{8,8,12}}
```

I get:

```
{{3,1,1}}
```

**Then**, I'd like to add this list to the original, still keeping the modular bounds:

```
{{3,1,1}}
+
{{4,4,6}}
=
{{2,5,7}}
```

And then repeat this process several times, always adding to the previous line:

```
{{4,4,6}}
{{2,5,7}}
{{0,6,8}}
{{3,0,9}}
etc.
```

Assuming you've followed my so far, how would I do that?

Comment: Your explanation doesn't seem to match your numbers.  Why is the 6 not doubled to 12 in the first step?  How does the 2 in {2,5,1} go to 0? 2*2 + 4 is not 0 mod 5.

Comment: @wxffles Should be fixed now. Feel free to give it a once-over. I can be quite mistake prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with

```
p = 6;
plist = Table[Prime[n], {n, 3, p - 1}]
bmod = Outer[Mod, {3*Prime[p]}, plist] // Flatten
(* {5, 7, 11} *)
(* {4, 4, 6} *)
```

the first result is obtained by

```
Thread[Mod[2 bmod, plist]]
(* {3, 1, 1} *)
```

To obtain the next results, use

```
NestList[Thread[Mod[# + bmod, plist]] &, %, 5]
(* {{3, 1, 1}, {2, 5, 7}, {1, 2, 2}, {0, 6, 8}, {4, 3, 3}, {3, 0, 9}} *)
```

which adds `bmod` to the previous result, modulo the corresponding prime in `plist`.

**Addendum**

To test whether any of the results immediately above contain `2` or `4`, as requested in a comment, use

```
MemberQ[#, (2 | 4)] & /@ %
(* {False, True, True, False, True, False} *)
```

Comment: You're right. My bad. I'll edit, and give this a shot shortly. Thanks!

Comment: Does what I want! Thanks!

Comment: Hey, you've already been immensely helpful, but would you mind one more thing? I need to apply "$MemberQ$" to each individual list in that final line to test if either 2 or 4 are elements of the list. Looking for an output of "False, True, True, False, True, False" but I'm just getting the single output of "True". Thanks for helping out a newb! =)

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed  I must not understand your last comment.  There are three elements in every sublist.  In any case, you probably should apply `Map` to the list to apply whatever criterion you wish to each sublist.  I can take a look tomorrow morning, if you like.

Comment: Great, I'll look into Map and give it a try. I'll let you know if I'm still having trouble. Thanks!

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed  I added `Map` of `MemberQ` to the end of my answer to address your comment.  Best wishes.